# FInd the names of customers are interested in every artist

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am looking for customer names of customers who have an interest in all artists.

I understand that in relational algebra, I can use the division operator, however I do not understand the SQL format in doing so.

I have these tables with columns:

```
customer (customerID, firstname, lastname)
artist (artistID)
customer_interest_in_artists (artistID, customerID)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a simple `MIN()` construct:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, MIN(ci.customerID IS NOT NULL) AS interest_all
FROM artist
LEFT JOIN customer_interest_in_artists ci USING (artistID)
LEFT JOIN customer c USING (customerID)
GROUP BY c.customerID
HAVING interest_all = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

1. Identify the customers for whom the number of rows in the customer_interest_in_artists table is equal to the number of rows in the artists table.

or

2. Identify the customers for whom there does not exist a row in the customer_interest_in_artists table for one or more artists.

The first option os probably easiest to implement, as you can already probably get the number of rows per customer (hint: join, count(*), and group) and compare the number per customer with the number of rows in artists -- hint: having count(*) = (a subquery)

Answer (score 0):

for ORACLE, I use this...
but i don't think mine is the most elegant of all answers, anyway, here it is!

```
SELECT c.FIRSTNAME, c.LASTNAME, c.CUSTOMERID
FROM DTOOHEY.CUSTOMER c, DTOOHEY.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT cai
WHERE c.CUSTOMERID = cai.CUSTOMERID 
AND c.CUSTOMERID IN 
(SELECT cai.CUSTOMERID
  FROM DTOOHEY.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT cai
  GROUP BY cai.CUSTOMERID
  HAVING COUNT (*) = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM DTOOHEY.ARTIST)
)
GROUP BY c.FIRSTNAME, c.LASTNAME, c.CUSTOMERID;
```

based on my limited knowledge, the flow of command is:

1) I am trying to get the customer ID, first name and last name of customer 

2) I am getting it from the 2 tables (cai and c)

3) trying to join the 2 tables to give me a single data set

4) where the c.customerid is to be gathered in...

this is where the magic begins!!!

5) select the customerID (the single CustomerID)

6) from this table cai

7) group the result based on customerID, this is what gives the single CustomerID Value that you need...

8) having COUNT (*) - having the count of customerID value, to that of equal of the number of count of artists in the dtoohey.artist table.


the main logic is that the number of artist in the artist table (which is 11), exist in the CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT in the same quantity. As such, we can tally the result of count from the ARTIST Table into the CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT table.

Answer (score -1):

I think these will useful to you

```
SELECT a.customerID, c.artistID  from customer a 
join customer_interest_in_artists b on a.customerID = b. customerID 
join artist c on c.artistID = b.artistID
```

Thank you.

Comment: So, this lists the id's for artists in whom the customers are interested -- it doesn't really answer the question.